# Update sortable by removing <li>

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to update the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)sortable, when I am removing an `<li>` element by a button 'click'.

```
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
      $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'updatesort.php'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Now it only updates when the user drag&drop the `<li>` elements.

**UPDATE (`html`):**

```
<ul id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">
  <li id="item-1"><button class="removeli">remove</button></li>
  <li id="item-2"><button class="removeli">remove</button></li>
  <li id="item-3"><button class="removeli">remove</button></li>
  <li id="item-4"><button class="removeli">remove</button></li>
  <li id="item-5"><button class="removeli">remove</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post your html code?

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez I updated the HTML code!

Answer (score 0):

By using:

```
$("#sortable button.removeli").on("click", function () {
     $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

You might try something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
      $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'updatesort.php'
      });
    }
  });
  $("#sortable button.removeli").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">
  <li id="item-1">
    Item 1
    <button class="removeli">remove</button>
  </li>
  <li id="item-2">
    Item 2
    <button class="removeli">remove</button>
  </li>
  <li id="item-3">
    Item 3
    <button class="removeli">remove</button>
  </li>
  <li id="item-4">
    Item 4
    <button class="removeli">remove</button>
  </li>
  <li id="item-5">
    Item 5
    <button class="removeli">remove</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If the CSS class .removeli is used anywhere, clicking that element would result in a removal of the parent, which may not be limited to the scope of this list which uses buttons.  It may be better to be more specific.  Address the buttons as **button.removeli** and specify a filter of **'li'** when you access the parent.

Comment: @KenGregory Agree with you. I've updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine as well for me:

```
$(".removeli").click(function() {
  //
  // get <li>-id for removing it from the database
  //

  $(this).closest("li").remove();

  var data = $("#sortable").sortable('serialize');
  $.ajax({
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'updatesort.php'
  });
});
```